# How to prove infinite product converging to sin and cos?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

How to prove following statements in the simplest way:
$$
\sin(x)=x\prod\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}\Big),\quad
\cos(x)=\prod\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2(2n-1)^2}\Big).
$$
We are learning infinite products, but the teacher just gave it to us without proof. I`ve read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) and that material is too hard to understand(i mean Weierstrass factorization theorem, as proof follows from it). Is there any simpler way?